# Make year in references page have brackets as in (Year) with chicago

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, brackets, biblatex-chicago

I'm using the chicago package, specifically I have used the code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,captions=tableabove, english]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{extarrows}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate15,maxcitenames=2,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
```

which correctly display the citation as Author (Year) within the text. However, in the references page, I do not get the Year in brackets. How can I fix that without abandoning biblatex-chicago?

For my full tex file: pastebin.com/KZd5Vu5K

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: While your question is fairly clear without a full code example, you can make our lives much easier by showing us a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that we can just copy, paste and compile. As your question stands now we have to do additional work before we can begin to answer your question. You can remove this obstacle and make it easier for you to get help quickly.

Comment: My system does not have `authordate15` any more. It has been removed as obsolete. Would you be OK with `authordate`?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Unfrotunately, authordate doesn't help. For my minimized latex file, please go to https://pastebin.com/KZd5Vu5K - but note that I have not included the Literature file (sorry, I have no idea how to include it in the tex file, I just load the Literatur.bib file)

Comment: It's not about `authordate` helping. It's more about me not being able to help you if you insist on `authordate15` since I can't run a file using that style. I will have a look if `authordate` is acceptable, but I can't promise anything since the code is quite full on. Have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864 for how to write proper MWEs with bibliography files. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/569/ if you prefer German instructions.

Comment: No, no, I don't insist on authordate15, it's the same as authordate from what I've tested. Thank you so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messing with `biblatex-chicago` is not always that easy since the style needs to do a lot of work to implement the exact requirements of the Chicago manual of Style.

The following will wrap the year in the bibliography in round brackets. The macro `cmsbibyear` is a copy of the original definition in `chicago-authordate.bbx` with `\printtext{\bibopenparen}` and `\printtext{\bibcloseparen}%` added. The prefered method of using `\printtext[parens]` could not be used because it would introduce a group that kept certain `\clearfield` operations local. I have changed the code so that you get "Author (Year)." and not "Author. (Year)." if you want the period between "Author" and "(Year)" just comment out the `\setunit{\addspace}%`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate,maxcitenames=2,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cmsbibyear}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext{\bibopenparen}%
  \printunit{}%
  \iftoggle{cms@origlabel}%
    {\usebibmacro{origyear+labelyear}}%
    {\iftoggle{cms@bothlabelnew}%
       {\usebibmacro{bothyear+oldstyle}}%
       {\iftoggle{cms@bothlabelold}%
          {\usebibmacro{bothyear+oldstyle}}%
          {\usebibmacro{labelyear+extrayear}}}}%
  \printtext{\bibcloseparen}%
  \ifcsdef{@cms@tempdate}%
    {\toggletrue{\@cms@tempdate}}%
    {}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,geer,worman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! However, as in your example here, the date is added twice: at the beginning with brackets and at the end without. (In my Latex, sometimes at the end also with brackets) How can I leave the one at the end out? Is that intended?

Comment: @mathlete Mhhh. Good catch, I didn't see that. I have changed the code to use a less elegant method that avoids the grouping `\printtext` introduces. The picture has not been updated to reflect the changes.

Comment: thanks a lot! You're definitely my hero for the weekend. <3

Just one remaining question: The (Year) looks like ( Year) however in the some special case (see picture below), there seems to be an extra space. How can I remove it? https://i.imgur.com/gmZSeTB.png

The ____ lines are those who have the same author as the one above that line btw.

Comment: @mathlete I added a fix for that as well (hopefully for all cases).

Comment: much love to you! Thanks a lot. I wish I could thank you by spending you some coffee and cake.

Comment: @mathlete I'll take you up on the cake if you ever come to Lower Saxony. If the answer helped you, you can accept it using the green checkmark on the top left newt to the question.